# PDFBox - Splitting one single pdf into multiple pdf files

Tags: java, pdfbox

My requirement is, i have to split a large pdf file into multiple small pdf files. I have a 10000 pages pdf file and i want to split the file into 1000 files with 10 pages each. I tried to split the file using pdfbox api. I am able to split the file as per my requirement and also it works fine with the file having small no of pages. But when i tried with 10000 pages, it is taking huge time, ie) in hours. In actual scenario i may even get pdf file with more than 20000 pages and more than 5000 splits.

The time to split is reducing based on the no of split. If i try to split the same file into 100*100 pages, it is taking less time. Can anyone please validate my code and check if i am doing it in a right way or i can add code to make the performance better.

Note: I cannot use 'iText' since this is for client specific project. Is there any api available to split the pdf file other than iText and pdfbox

Please refer my below code

```
public class Test {

private static String sourceFolderPath = "/local_path/PDFSplitter_perf/10000_pages/";
private static String outputPath = sourceFolderPath+"output/";
private static String pdfFileName = sourceFolderPath+"test_1.pdf";
private static int pageCount = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    splitUsingPDFBox(pdfFileName);
}

public static void splitUsingPDFBox(String pdfFilePath) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException{ 
    try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilePath));) {
        int i = 1;

        while(i<10000){
            int startPage = i;
            int endPage = i + (pageCount-1);
            String chidlPdfFile = outputPath+"/"+startPage+"_"+endPage+".pdf";

            Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
            splitter.setStartPage(startPage);
            splitter.setEndPage(endPage);
            splitter.setSplitAtPage(endPage);

            List<PDDocument> pages = splitter.split(document);

            PDDocument pd = null;
            try{
                pd = pages.get(0);
                pd.save(chidlPdfFile);
            }finally{
               if( pd != null ){
                  pd.close();
               }
            }
    } 
}
}
```

}

Comment: *"Note: I cannot use 'iText' since this is for client specific project."* - ***A)*** your question clearly is pdfbox specific. Thus,  there is no need to justify for not using itext. But ***B)*** your justification as is doesn't make sense.

Comment: You use the splitter class in a very ineffective way. Why do you load your original pdf again and again for each single result file? If you don't set start and end for the splitter, a single call to `splitUsingPDFBox` would suffice...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that i am loading same document again and again. I have modified the code to load it one time. But for your second question, as per the requirement, the page count will not be always same. For, example i have to split like 1-25, 26-30, 31-49 etc.so i have to set start and end page

Comment: *"I have modified the code to load it one time"* - and? Did the speed improve?

Comment: i can see improvement in performance. But still it is taking huge time to split the files

Comment: You could also add the pages to new PDDocument objects and save these. But don't close them before all is finished because the resources exist in all documents.